# always garbage in integer variable

Tags: c, integer

this code is an Integral program  that calculate functions f(x)

and here .. the function is f(x)= x^2

```
int main()
{
float integral;
float a=0,b=0;
int n=1024;
float h;
float x;
int i;

float f(float x);

printf("Enter a, b \n");
scanf("%f %f" , &a, &b);
printf("Enter  n\n");
scanf("%d" , &n);



h=(b-a)/n;
integral = (f(a)+f(b))/2;
x=a;
for (i = 0; i <= n-1; n++)
{
    x = x + h;
    integral = integral + f(x);
}
integral = integral * h ;

printf("with n = %d trapezoids, our esrimate\n", n );
printf("of the integral from %f to %f =  %f\n", a , b , integral);

system("pause");
return 0;

}


float f(float x)
{
  return x*x;
}
```

the output of n always garbage .. i don't know why 
where is my wrong ??

the question is stupid

bu i really tired looking for the wrong 
[image]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text; post the text itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's your error: `for (i = 0; i <= n-1; n++)`. You increment `n` instead of `i`.

Answer (score 3):

The bug lies here, probably typo:

```
for (i = 0; i <= n-1; n++)
```

By the way there is another typo in the program: *esrimate* should be *estimate* :)

Answer (score 0):

you have to clean the keyboard memory

[fflush](http://openbook.galileocomputing.de/c_von_a_bis_z/016_c_ein_ausgabe_funktionen_013.htm#mj916b50e93a84be77b338cb8023b6fafc)

```
printf("Enter a, b \n");
scanf("%f %f" , &a, &b);
   fflush(stdin);
printf("Enter  n\n");
scanf("%d" , &n);
```